# Laravel stancl/tenancy Tenancy with Api Routes

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

can someone help me to understand how I can configure this package
https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy
to accept my api routes.

I have already made a project... and now I want to add Tenancy.
I dont understand where to move my api routes... and how access them.

thanks in advance